# Can a power bank power a stepper motor with these specs?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, stepper-motor

I'm planning to use an Arduino to control a stepper motor and I want to use a typical power bank (that would normally be used to charge a phone) to power the stepper motor. Here are the specs:

- The [power bank](https://www.amazon.ca/Anker-PowerCore-Technology-High-Capacity-Compatible/dp/B07S829LBX/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=power%2Bbank&qid=1605537802&sr=8-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQ1NOOVU2SktUWklMJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwODMzNDExMlYwTEUxQU1PM0YwSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDEwMTUxTUFTQVZTSFJCOTBGJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ&th=1) outputs 5 V (I'm not sure what the current rating for output is).
- The [stepper motor](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/trinamic-motion-control-gmbh/QSH5718-41-28-055/4843428) is rated at 2 VDC and the current rating is 2.8 A.

Would this above set-up work? If so, would I be able to get away with a stepper motor that's 3.3 VDC/3 A?

Comment: You must know how much the powerbank can provide current. And then calculate the power. And use a switch mode regulator to step down the voltage. To run the larger motor you need 5V 2A in practice.

Comment: You don't have to run motors at full power

Comment: @Justme, I think the typical output for a 5V power bank is 2A. Does this mean that the motor won't be able to reach its full power potential?

Comment: @user253751 what's the reason it wouldn't be able to use full power? does my previous comment to Justme make sense for the reason?

Comment: are you missing something from your post? ... a stepping motor needs more than a power supy

Comment: @jsotola I think I will need a driver as well but that wasn't too relevant for this question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes ... you are right about the relevance, now that you mention it

Comment: It might work, but generally speaking it's a bad idea and likely to put a lot of stress on things.  Stepper motors aren't a usual choice for a battery powered system, why do you want a stepper anyway?  And if you _were_ going to use a stepper, you should consider if you can use a smaller one or one with a higher impedance coil, or if you do need torque at speed you may want to run this motor from a chopping drive powered at 12 volts or more.  **Basically, there's too much missing from your question for a meaningful reply to be possible**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power bank you link to can deliver a claimed \$\small{2.4 \rm \ A \cdot 5 \rm \ V} = 12 \rm \ W\$ on one USB port (if you use only one port).

Using a step-down DC/DC converter to go to \$\small \rm 2\ V\$, assuming 85% efficiency, would give you a maximum of \$\small{0.85} \cdot {\normalsize \rm {12 \ W \over 2\ V}} \approx \rm 5\ A\$, which is more than enough.

The claimed capacity of the power pack is \$\small\rm72\ Wh\$; assuming 75% of that is usable, it should be able to deliver \$\small\rm 2.8\ A \cdot 2\ V = 5.6\ W\$ to the motor for \$\small \rm 0.75 \cdot \normalsize{72\ Wh \over 5.6\ W} \small \approx 9.5 \space hours\$, assuming a 100% efficient motor driver.

The calculations for the other motor are left as an excercise to the reader (I have always wanted to say that).

Comment: Thank you! This answer is really clear.